# Spring-Boot Executable-Jar NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an application created using Spring-Boot.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And have my Appplication.java annotated as shown below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
...
```

This works when I run it inside eclipse without any problems but, when I generate an executable jar it throws the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No    qualifying bean of type [com.company.engine.services.BaseDao] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:319)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:987)
```

Any ideas?

pom.xml

```
<profiles>
 <profile>
 <id>prod</id>
 <build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <configuration>
  <source>1.6</source>
  <target>1.6</target>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
 <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
  <execution>
  <phase>install</phase>
  <goals>
  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
  </goals>
  </execution>
  </executions>
 </plugin>
 <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
  <archive>
  <manifest>
  <mainClass>com.company.engine.Application</mainClass>      
  </manifest>
  </archive>
  <descriptorRefs>
   <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
  </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</profile>
</profiles>
```

**Project Structure**

**com.company.engine**

Application.java

**com.company.engine.model**

Domain.java

**com.company.engine.service**

CrudRepositoryJavaClasses

**Solution from @Oleg Majewski with minor modifications :**

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.company.engine.Application</mainClass>
        <layout>ZIP</layout>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
          <goal>repackage</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You are using Spring boot then use the spring-boot maven plugin to generate the jar file not the maven assembly plugin.

Comment: Thanks. You answered first but in the comment portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use spring-boot-maven-plugin instead of doing maven-assembly-plugin and maven-dependency-plugin by yourself:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
             <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
             </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After you can build the jar like this:

```
$ mvn package
$ ls target/*.jar
```