# spring boot jar NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, jar, executable-jar

I builded spring boot application which works well if I start it with `mvn spring-boot:run` but trying to run it `java -jar jarName.jar` results in error `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'HomeService' available`

here is my pom.xml with `spring-boot-maven-plugin` like it is described here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html and here [Spring-Boot Executable-Jar NoSuchBeanDefinitionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979913/spring-boot-executable-jar-nosuchbeandefinitionexception)

```
    <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/${profileName}</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- source output directory -->
                        <outputDirectory>target/metamodel</outputDirectory>
                        <!-- <processors> -->
                        <!-- <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor> -->
                        <!-- </processors> -->
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <profiles>
                    <profile>dev</profile>
                    <profile>live</profile>
                </profiles>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>live</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <delete file="src/main/resources/application.properties" />
                                    <copy file="src/main/resources/application-live.properties"
                                        tofile="src/main/resources/application.properties" />
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <delete file="src/main/resources/application.properties" />
                                    <copy file="src/main/resources/application-dev.properties"
                                        tofile="src/main/resources/application.properties" />
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

here is App class

```
@Configuration 
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan (basePackages = { "myProject.status" })
public class App {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws BeansException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    logger.info("APPLICATION STARTED");

    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    logger.info(context.getBean(HomeService.class).home());

}
```

here is HomeService

```
package myProject.status.service;
@Service
public class HomeService {

    public String home() {
        return "application works";
    }
}
```

I tried also to get a bean in `@PostConstruct` method, where everything and all Autowires should be ready, it also does not work.

What is the difference between `mvn spring-boot:run` and `mvn package` ? How could I build correct jar?

Thanks!

Comment: Should you just be using the spring boot plugin rather than using the Maven jar plugin ?

Comment: @PaulNUK even if I disable all profiles and remover that section from pom an spring-boot-maven-plugin configuration I get the same error

Comment: Is your service class scanned while booting?

Comment: looks like it does not, so I get an error, but why? it work with spring-boot:run and @ComponentScan (basePackages = { "myProject.status" }) includes its package

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html here is documentation which I follow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476486/understanding-spring-boot-autowired postConstruct form this question also does not solve the error

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [$ mvn package spring-boot:repackage](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-include-maven-plugin) to build a standalone executable jar.

The difference between `mvn spring-boot:run` and `mvn spring-boot:repackage` is that `spring-boot:run` for local run and debug, while `spring-boot:repackage` is to package for deployment.

Also, you need to specify `<packaging>jar</packaging>`.

Another comment for `App.java`, you can just use one annotation as [@SpringBootApplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html). It would cover all your three annotations, assuming `App.java` is in Package `myProject.status`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but it doesn't help, still the same error. I even add jar mode to spring-boot-maven-plugin configuration. I get the same jar. Looks like running from jar doesn't scan for autowire. It is not the first my spring boot project and it worked before. But not now.

Comment: Another projects were annotated with Springbootapplication and maybe it is the key point. Here I configure several datasources, which do not work with autoconfigutation for me. So I annotated it manually. I try to find possible difference between this annotations and the way the run from jar.

Comment: @Slava, if you can push your code somewhere, we can debug from there.

Comment: thank you for your time and help! Removing (basePackages = { "myProject.status" }) make the jar run

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. It is confusing, so I will try to figure out why it is so. To make jar run I should remove `(basePackages = { "myProject.status" })`

`@ComponentScan (basePackages = { "myProject.status" })` works with `mvn spring-boot:run` but only pure `@ComponentScan` works from jar. Actually it is really my root directory, so I do not need it, but the question, why does not it work from jar is opened. All classes are under this root directory, so it should find it there but maybe it does not scan any dependencies running from jar.

Thank you all, who replied to me!